# How to achieve "Feature Highlight" from Android in CSS / Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js, highlight

In Android you can highlight a component using the "[Feature Highlight](https://material.io/develop/ios/supporting/feature-highlights)" feature. This is a way to visually highlight a part of the screen to introduce users to new features and functionalities. See the following video for example: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/-8m8SaCNInc

Now I want to add this effect in a Vue in combination with Vuetify project, I can't find any existing libraries or example projects. For this reason, I want to make an attempt to recreate it myself.

Does anyone have an idea where to start or how I can recreate this easily?

[image: Example: Android Highlight Feature]

Comment: here's a start https://pastebin.com/m75k9shP

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not quite what I am looking for. In your example code, the content is wrapped in the overlay. However, in Android, the highlight is wrapped around the DOM element. I just added to the post a sample video of how it works in action.

Comment: I said "it's a start", as I don't actually know exactly what you want as you've provided ZERO code - and yes, you'd still want to use v-overlay, positioned accordingly for each feature, animated accordingly - I'm not going to do it all for you since I don't know what features you want to highlight and where they are in your app!